# Alternate row numbering in Word table

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

I have a table style set up to use banded rows. Each banded row will use heading style two with numbering. Is there any way to get that number into the No. column in the above picture without having to type it manually and without using VBA?

I know you can set row numbering, but I can't see how to have it affect alternate rows only, besides which the user may have used heading style two before they get to this table so I wouldn't know which number to start on.

Many thanks

Comment: This is certainly not a native feature of Word. Therefore, I do not believe this is possible without VBA. At least I have not been able to find anything indicating a way to accomplish this in the manner you desire.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Thanks for the confirmation.